# Running JWS remotely on 64-bit machine

Tags: 64-bit, java-web-start

The problem is that my JNLP file works locally on my 64-bit machine (running on my own machine), and locally and remotely on my 32-bit machine - but not remotely on the 64-bit machine (you see the Java 6... message for a looong time, and then it just terminates!).  Any suggestions about how to trouble-shoot this?  Should I specify different libraries for 64-bit and 32-bit?  FWIW the jnlp file looks like this (maybe quite wrong!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+"
  codebase="http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/graphicsstuff/">
<information>
  <title>DrawFBP</title>
  <vendor>J.P. Morrison Enterprises, Ltd.</vendor>
  <description>FBP Diagramming Tool</description>
  <icon href="DrawFBP-logo.jpg"/> 
</information>
<security> 
   <all-permissions/> 
</security>
<offline-allowed/>
<resources>
  <j2se version="1.6+"/>
  <j2se version="1.5"/>
  <jar href="DrawFBP_signed-2.3.jar" main="true"/>
   <extension name="javahelp" href="javahelp.jnlp">
   </extension>   
</resources>
<application-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

and javahelp.jnlp is as follows:

```
<!-- Java Network Launching Protocol file for JavaHelp 
(requires Java Web Start http://www.java.com/)  - thanks to www.koders.com --> 
<jnlp codebase="https://jwindows.dev.java.net/" href="javahelp.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
  <information>
    <title>Java Help</title>
    <vendor>Sun Microsystems</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://java.sun.com/products/javahelp/"/>
    <description>Java Help 2.0</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security>
   <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.5+"/> 
    <jar href="lib/jhall.jar" part="javahelp"/>
    <package name="javax.help" part="javahelp" recursive="true"/>
  </resources>
  <component-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to install both the 32-bit version of Java and the 64-bit version.  Very confusing, but apparently Java can figure out which to use!  It would be nice (but not essential) if someone could tell me why this works...?

PS I posted this to the Oracle forum, and nobody answered it either :-)  I will post this answer there too.